# Executar comandos de bash em C

Tags: c, string, bash

Estou usando a função `system("comando");` para executar comandos de bash num programa em C.

Contudo, estou com dificuldade para imprimir o valor de uma variável.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char* letra= "A";
    system("echo letra");
}
```

O que posso fazer para trabalhar com o conteúdo de uma variável de C para o bash e vice-versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode escrever uma [`Variadic Function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C) capaz de receber uma [`string de formatação`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) como argumento, possibilitando a manipulação de todos os tipos primitivos de forma padrão, veja só:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define CMD_TAM_MAX   (1024)

int systemf( const char * fmt, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    char cmd[ CMD_TAM_MAX + 1 ];

    va_start( args, fmt );
    vsnprintf( cmd, CMD_TAM_MAX + 1, fmt, args );
    va_end(args);

    return system(cmd);
}

int main( void )
{
    int i = 123;
    char ch = 'X';
    char * txt = "Ola Mundo!";
    float pi = 3.1415f;
    double dbl = 1234567890L;

    systemf( "echo int: %d", i );
    systemf( "echo char: %c", ch );
    systemf( "echo char*: %s", txt );
    systemf( "echo float: %f", pi );
    systemf( "echo double: %f", dbl );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
int: 123
char: X
char*: Ola Mundo!
float: 3.141500
double: 1234567890.000000
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/rsF7K8)

Para acessar as `variáveis de ambiente` do seu *shell*, você pode usar uma [`main()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++) com uma assinatura um pouco diferente da usual:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv, char **envp );
```

Onde `char ** envp` trata-se da lista de todas as `variáveis de ambiente` disponíveis, no formato `VARIAVEL=VALOR`, com um terminador `NULL` indicando o final, vejá só:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv, char **envp )
{
    char **env = NULL;

    for( env = envp; *env != NULL; env++ )
    {
        char * variavel = *env;
        printf( "%s\n", variavel );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
WORKSPACE=/tmp/a4a2fff3-ba98-4fda-9d1d-e31d83ac61ee
PWD=/home/0NxZg3
HOME=/home/0NxZg3
TMPDIR=/tmp/WpSkY2
TMPDIR_GLOBAL=/tmp/a4a2fff3-ba98-4fda-9d1d-e31d83ac61ee
SHLVL=0
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/dZQ4bJ)

Para acessar um `variavel de ambiente` específica dentro do seu programa, você pode usar a função [`getenv()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) da biblioteca padrão `stdlib.h`, veja só:

```
char * valor = getenv("PATH");
printf( "PATH=%s\n", valor );
```

Comment: Não conhecia esse `char **envp`. Eu sempre ia por `getenv`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: `char **envp` é suportado amplamente por vários compiladores, porém não faz parte do padrão `C` e nem `POSIX`.

Comment: @Lacobus no primeiro caso, na função que vc chamou de `systemf` como eu faria pra retornar o novo comando como uma string??

Answer (score 5):

Você quer imprimir formatado, mas em vez de mandar diretamente para o console irá capturar isso, seria algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* letra = "A";
    char *buffer = malloc(strlen(letra) + 6); //6 é o tamanho de "echo ", incluindo o terminador, dá para optimizar
    if (sprintf(buffer, "echo %s", letra) > 0) system(buffer);
    else printf("algo deu errado");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vR05V4). E [no **Coding Ground**](http://tpcg.io/9nwkl4). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Formating.c). Está um pouco diferente porque não posso acessar o `system()` nesses locais.

[Documentação do `sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Note que apesar da variável estar escrito `letra` está permitindo uma palavra, frase, ou um texto todo.

Comment: Faltou o vice-versa, do C pegar coisas do shell

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a pergunta não fala nada disso, fala de imprimir uma letra.

Comment: Último parágrafo: "O que posso fazer para trabalhar com o conteúdo de uma variável de C para o bash e vice-versa??"

Comment: É que não dá para saber o que ele quer fazer com isso, no fundo é uma não clara (ou ampla) se considerar isso. Colocou que quer fazer e não diz problema algum, você sabe que não é este tip ode pergunta que desejamos aqui. E estou considerando seriamente o fechamento, provavelmente deveria ter feito antes. Fui no que ele colocou e ignorei o resto, não posso especular o que ele quer. Ele pode querer manipular o que o a chamada do `system()` gerou de resultado no console ou algo assim.