# Bubble Sort em Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, classificação

```
def bubble_sort(list):
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[j] > list[j+1]:
                list[j], list[j+1] = list[j+1], list[j]
        else:
            continue
```

Acabei de fazer esse bubble sort, mas acabei percebendo que ele faz algumas interações desnecessárias por conta do for maior(i), gostaria de saber como parar todas as interações quando a lista estiver ordenada / saber quando a lista vai estar ordenada

Comment: O `range` deveria ir de 0 até `i - 1`. Aí você teria uma otimização boa. E o `else` é desnecessário mesmo =)

Comment: Creio que valha a lida desta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/64969

Comment: Testei em 2 listas mas só funcionou em uma, na outra ainda faltou um valor no meio ser ordenado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal usar um *flag* de controle para se determinar se a lista foi ordenada por completo:

```
def bubble_sort( lst ):
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        ok = True
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
                lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
                ok = False
    return lst

print(bubble_sort([7,6,5,4,9,1,6,2,4,9,0,3]))
```

Saída:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9, 9]
```

Em `Python`, tudo isso já está pronto e no mundo prático, não há a necessidade de tal implementação.

Toda essa parafernália pode ser substituida simplesmente por:

```
lst = [7,6,5,4,9,1,6,2,4,9,0,3]
print(sorted(lst))
```

Saída:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9, 9]
```